# How to get .woff and .tff files for Segoe UI Semilight font?

Tags: html, css, font-face

I want to use Segoe UI Semilight fonts in my web page.

For this purpose i need to use,

```
@font-face {
   font-family: Segoe UI Semilight;
   src: url(??);
}
```

1. Now i need to ask how to get src files - like `Segoe UI
   Semilight.woff` and `Segoe UI Semilight.tff`?
2. Where do I download it? Can anyone please share the link?

Comment: Is this the font your after? http://www.ufonts.com/download/segoe-ui-light/77996.html

Comment: You can then use a font converter to get the other font files and CSS: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: @AfromanJ thanks, but i need to download Segoe UI Semilight. not Segoe UI Light. if u have any other link please share

Comment: This might be it: http://bit.ly/1hrBCmh, you should be able to convert to `.ttf`

Answer (score 5):

The Segoe family are copyrighted fonts and as far as I know, Microsoft does not allow embedding them on websites. You might be better off finding a similar looking font on Font Squirrel, Google Fonts or a similar service offering free fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Just run our windows 8/10 device, navigate to `C:\Windows\Fonts` directory, search for `segoe ui`, right click in segoe ui and copy it, paste it on the desktop, now you will get all the fonts of segoe ui font family in ttf format, choose the required one.

Note: Maybe there is the risk of lawsuits if you use any of the font in your webpage.